# Get Geometry from revit element

Tags: ironpython, revit, revitpythonshell

I have Created the following code and Iam stuck at extracting geometry from the element(in my case it going to be a CAD import)

I am expecting solutions to these:

1. How to classify or filter geometry types in the iron python.
2. what is a indexer#

I really didnt understand this but tried this too..

options = Autodesk.Revit.DB.Options()

Selected = Ui.Selection.GetElementIds()

test=(Selected[0])

Cad = doc.GetElement(test)

curves = Cad.Geometry

print(curves)

NewCurve = doc.Create.NewDetailCurve(view,curves[options])

Actual code:

```
#Import Autodesk stuffs
import clr
import System
clr.AddReference('ProtoGeometry')
from Autodesk.DesignScript.Geometry import *

clr.AddReference('RevitAPI')
import Autodesk
from Autodesk.Revit.DB import *

clr.AddReference('RevitAPIUI')
from Autodesk.Revit.UI.Selection import *

clr.AddReference('RevitNodes')
import Revit
clr.ImportExtensions(Revit.GeometryConversion)
clr.ImportExtensions(Revit.Elements)

clr.AddReference('RevitServices')
import RevitServices
from RevitServices.Persistence import DocumentManager

# Import iron python packages
import sys
pyt_path = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib'
sys.path.append(pyt_path)

import RevitServices
from RevitServices.Persistence import DocumentManager
from RevitServices.Transactions import TransactionManager


app = __revit__.Application
Ui = __revit__.ActiveUIDocument
doc = __revit__.ActiveUIDocument.Document
view = doc.ActiveView


from Autodesk.Revit.UI import Selection

Selected = Ui.Selection.GetElementIds()

test=(Selected[0])

Cad = doc.GetElement(test)

curves = Cad.Geometry

print(curves)

NewCurve = doc.Create.NewDetailCurve(view,curves)
```

Comment: Forgot to mention that I was getting the error saying that  "expected Curve, got indexer#"

Comment: If one of Jeremy's replies below answer your question, be sure to 'Accept as Answer' the post

Answer (score 0):

You should debug through your code step by step. In the debugger, you can see the actual values of each of your variables. I believe, just from looking at your code, that your variable `curves` is a `GeometryElement` instance. You need to dig deeper into the internal structure of that element to access the actual `Curve` object that you feed into `NewDetailCurve`. `NewDetailCurve` is complaining that you are passing it a more complex object, not a `Curve` object.

Answer (score 0):

You are in luck. The method `GetCurvesInPlane` in my latest blog post on [Retrieving Section View Intersection Cut Geometry](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2019/05/retrieving-section-view-intersection-cut-geometry.html) shows how to dig deeper into a `GeometryElement` and extract the `Curve` objects contained within it.